# Why is hangfire not printing out the message in my method

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks, backgroundworker, hangfire, hangfire-console

I have written a simple console app that should print a message every minute. I do get the first print message saying "starting" however i do not get the message in the `PrintTest()`

method in my console. What is the reason for this ? By the way, this is a .net core console application.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        GlobalConfiguration
            .Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(@"Server=127.0.0.1,1433; Database=HFTest; User Id=sa; Password=Password123");

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate((() => PrintTest()), Cron.Minutely());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void PrintTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `BackgroundJobServer` with `using` block and put your RecurringJob in it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        GlobalConfiguration
            .Configuration
            .UseColouredConsoleLogProvider()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(@"Server=127.0.0.1,1433; Database=HFTest; User Id=sa; Password=Password123");

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => PrintTest(), Cron.Minutely());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

Refer to https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html